# Find if a string contains " "

Tags: java, string, java.util.scanner

I am trying to find if a string contains a space, and if it does print out an error. Once the space is found, I have to use substring() to print out everything before the space on one line, and everything after the space on the second line. Here is what I have tried:

```
while (type.hasNext())
{
         String word = type.nextLine(); // save the word that is tped into variable 'word'

         String nextLine = word; // save the 'word' as variable 'nextLine'

         String check = " "; //save the white space that is typed as 'check'

         int space = check.indexOf(' '); //check the index of space


         if (word.contains(" "))
         {
            System.out.println(word);

            String test = check.substring(0, space);

            System.out.println(word);

            String test2 = check.substring(space, word.length());

            System.out.println(word);

         } 

         else
          System.out.println("ERROR: There is no space!"); }
```

Thanks for help

Comment: `String.contains(String sequence);`

Answer (score 2):

It is as simple as this:

```
String.contains(" ");    [where String is the name of your String variable].
```

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains(java.lang.CharSequence)

Comment: `contains(" ")` is a substring search, and is not as efficient as `indexOf(' ') != -1`, which is about as easy to write and understand.

Comment: @Andreas No it isn't...                                                                           public boolean contains(CharSequence s) {
           return indexOf(s.toString()) > -1;}                                                          This was taken directly from java source code of string class..

Comment: You missed the difference between `indexOf(' ')` and `indexOf(" ")`. First is a *character* search, which is more efficient than the *substring* search of the second.

Answer (score 1):

This is not how `indexOf()` works.  Did you [read the documentation?](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf-int-)

> Returns:
>   the index of the first occurrence of the character in the character sequence represented by this object, or -1 if the character does not occur.

```
 if (check.indexOf(' ') < 0)
 {
     System.out.println("ERROR: There is no space!");  
 }
```